# cannot parse the debug map for

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, bitcode

i just open an app which belongs long before to add some view controllers but when i tried to debug ... i am getting errors like below...
i checked so many answers but no result..please help on this issue....

> ld: library not found for -lOAuth clang: error: linker command failed
>   with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
>
> error: cannot parse the debug map for
>   "/Users/apple/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iSimran-bxmxuypppzpidjgjkuuvnjhjbtnq/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/iSimran.app/iSimran":
>   No such file or directory

Comment: try to run the app again after removing derived data

Answer (score 2):

If you are not using BitCode, make sure that BitCode is disabled, default is YES, change it to NO.

```
Build -> Build Options -> Enable Bitcode
```

Answer (score 0):

For my case, I added a duplicated library to `cocoapods` which caused this error. After I remove the dependency and thus eliminate the duplicated warnings being thrown during the build process, the linker error is gone.

Answer (score 0):

Adding Facebook SDK in my document directory fixed my error. In my code, Facebook SDK was implemented manually and the location was "Document/FacebookSDK". This was my trailer & error fix. but this works for me.